# Join 3 different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on three different tables that are related for actors, movies they played in and what they were cast as in the movie. My current problem is I cannot get the Movie title to correlate correctly with the Actors Name and the role they played. Here is my SQL syntax. And a screenshot of my output. Obviously the movie title does not match with the actor. For instance Robert Loggia and AlPacino should both have the movie Scarface next to them. What am I missing here?

[image: current results]

```
SELECT a.fname, lname, c.characterRole, m.title, salary
FROM Actor a, Castings c, Movie m 
where a.actorID = c.actorId and a.actorID = m.movieId
```

[image: movies table]

Comment: You need yo use INNER JOIN. Take a look of that in w3school https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

The query you want looks like:

```
SELECT a.fname, lname, c.characterRole, m.title, salary
FROM Actor a JOIN
     Castings c
     ON a.actorID = c.actorId JOIN
     Movie m 
     ON c.movieId = m.movieId;
```

Equating `actorId` and `movieId` doesn't make sense.  Movie ids should be connected to movie ids.

Comment: if I wanted to lets say get the salary of a movie actor and we don't know the actorId but we know the actors name, how would we word the subquery to do this?

Comment: SELECT salary
FROM Castings 
WHERE fname = (SELECT fname 
               FROM Actor
               WHERE fname = 'Paul');

Comment: @hotrod28 ... I would be surprised if `castings` had a column for the actor's first name.  It should just have `ActorId`.

Comment: you are correct castings only has the ActorId but what I would like to do now is display the salary for an actor if we only know their name and not their ActorId number

Comment: @hotrod28 . . . (1) You can just add a `where` clause to the query in this answer.  (2) If that doesn't do what you want, ask another question, with sample data, desired results, and your attempt at the solution.

Comment: thanks for all your help, when I get near my computer later I’ll give it a try and if I’m still stuck I’ll revise the the question and post what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the Castings table has a movieId to be linked to the Movie table

```
SELECT 
a.fname AS FirstName, 
a.lname AS LastName, 
c.characterRole, 
m.title, 
c.salary
FROM Movie m
JOIN Castings c ON c.movieId = m.movieId
JOIN Actor a ON a.actorID = c.actorId
```